# Can I register to vote in Connecticut?

Tags: voting, elections, politics

I'm attending college in Connecticut, where I've lived on-campus for approximately 3 months. I'm from out-of-state, however, and reside in Connecticut only during the school year. Am I eligible to vote in Connecticut? The online registration form asks me to confirm that I'm a 'resident' before continuing. I've spent a considerable amount of time searching relevant resources and the internet, and there is a considerable amount of conflicting information out there. I've tried speaking with voter registration representatives, to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes, you can register in Connecticut.

Connecticut previously limited voting eligibility to "permanent" residents, but it later changed that to limit it to people with at least year's worth of residency, and then six months' of residency.

Under current law, though, a voter need only be a ["bona fide" resident of "some town"](https://www.cga.ct.gov/current/pub/chap_143.htm#sec_9-12) in Connecticut. This means you need only to have legitimately moved into the city with some actual intent to stay, even if not forever.

The deadline is tomorrow, so [register now](https://voterregistration.ct.gov/OLVR/welcome.do).